# while deploying on remote server i am getting an error' Error: connect ECONNREFUSED 10.208.26.206:21'

Tags: node.js, gulp, autodeploy

Error: connect ECONNREFUSED 10.208.26.206:21
at TCPConnectWrap.afterConnect [as oncomplete] (node:net:1161:16)
at TCPConnectWrap.callbackTrampoline (node:internal/async_hooks:130:17)

this is the error i am getting. before the main project i was trying to deploy this on my server given from organisation but getting this error.

```
*code**
var gulp = require('gulp');
var uglify = require('gulp-uglify');
var csso = require('gulp-csso');
var htmlmin = require('gulp-htmlmin');
var browserSync = require('browser-sync').create();
var reload = browserSync.reload;
var gutil = require('gulp-util');
var ftp = require('vinyl-ftp');
//var GulpSSHDeploy = require('gulp-ssh-deploy').GulpSSHDeploy;


var styleSrc = './src/css/*.css';
var styleDest = './dist/css';
var jsSrc = './src/js/*.js';
var jsDest = './dist/js';
var pageSrc = './src/html/*.html';
var pageDest = './dist/html';

var styleWatch = './src/css/**/*.css';
var jsWatch = './src/js/**/*.js';
var pageWatch = './src/html/**/*.html';

var user = 'user';
var password = 'password';
var host = 'test-vm-xyz.xyz.xyz.in';
var port = 21;
var localFilesGlob = ['./src/**/*'];
var remoteFolder = './home/project/myApp/';

gulp.task('style', function () {
   return gulp.src(styleSrc)
        .pipe(csso())
   .pipe(gulp.dest(styleDest))
});  

    gulp.task('js', function () {
       return gulp.src(jsSrc)
        .pipe(uglify())
        .pipe(gulp.dest(jsDest));
    });

    gulp.task('page', function () {
        return gulp.src(pageSrc)
        .pipe(htmlmin({collapseWhitespace: true}))
        .pipe(gulp.dest(pageDest));
    });

    gulp.task('browser-sync', function () {
        browserSync.init({
           open:'external',
              host: host,
                proxy: 'http://' + host + ':' + port,
                port: port,
                notify: false,
                ghostMode: false});

        });

        // helper function to upload a file
 gulp.task('deploy', function () {
     var conn = ftp.create({
         host: host,
         user: user,
         password: password,
         parallel: 10,
         log: gutil.log});
         console.log('Connecting to ' + host + ':' + port);
         console.log('Uploading files to ' + remoteFolder);
         console.log('Using user ' + user + ' with password ' + password);
       
        return gulp.src(localFilesGlob, {base: './src', buffer: false})
        
            .pipe(conn.newer(remoteFolder))
            .pipe(conn.dest(remoteFolder));
    });

    

    gulp.task('ftp-deploy-watch', function () {
        var conn = getFtpConnection();
             return gulp.src(localFilesGlob, { base: './src', buffer: false })
                .pipe(conn.newer(remoteFolder)) // only upload newer files
                .pipe(conn.dest(remoteFolder));
        });
    

    
    gulp.task('watch', function () {
      
        gulp.watch(styleWatch, gulp.parallel('style'));
        gulp.watch(jsWatch,  gulp.parallel('js'));
        gulp.watch(pageWatch, gulp.parallel('page'));
        // gulp.watch(GulpSSHDeploy.watch_files).on('change', reload);g
    });
    
    gulp.task('default', gulp.series('style','js','page', 'watch'),function(){
        return console.log('Gulp is running...');
     });
```

Comment: Your remote server doesn't support FTP.

Comment: thanks but now i am getting this error
Error: Timed out while making data connection
    at Timeout.<anonymous> (D:\my-project\gulp\node_modules\ftp\lib\connection.js:901:12)
    at listOnTimeout (node:internal/timers:557:17)
    at processTimers (node:internal/timers:500:7)

Comment: That's still an FTP issue. See [this comment on the `vinyl-ftp` repo](https://github.com/morris/vinyl-ftp/issues/65#issuecomment-497302967).